# How does the size of a hole in dimension lumber affect strength?

Tags: wood-properties

I've looked around the internet but cannot find a good explanation for this question.

Generally speaking, will a 1-1/2” hole in the dead center of a board (say, the biggest common hardware store found material: 2x12 Doug fir) weaken the structural integrity of the board regardless of the length, knots, etc.?

Or, put a different way: how big of a hole can one make in dimension lumber until the structure of that lumber is compromised?

Comment: I'm confused between the `3/8"` hole noted in your title and the `1 1/2"` hole mentioned in your question body, but neither, when located in the center of the 12" dimension of a 2x12, will cause any significant weakening of the board. In home construction, you're generally allowed (by code) to drill a hole up to 1/3 the width of the board before it's considered compromised and an engineering solution is required to strengthen it for the lost wood - for your 2x12 example, you could drill a 4" hole, centered on the width, without significant concern.

Comment: @FreeMan, answers go below \*cough*

Comment: _mea culpa_, @Graphus... :)

Comment: @Graphus _little_ bit of the pot calling the kettle a specific colour ;)

Comment: @jdv, oh yes absolutely. But I was actually quoting a Comment FreeMan made to me about 2 weeks ago :-))

Comment: Well, we can all use this reminder...

Comment: And, @jdv, I did pick up on Graphus' intent and took it the way he meant it. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused between the 3/8" hole noted in your title and the 1 1/2" hole mentioned in your question body, but neither, when located in the center of the 12" dimension of a 2x12, will cause any significant weakening of the board.

In home construction, you're generally allowed (by code) to drill a hole up to 1/3 the width of the board before it's considered compromised and an engineering solution is required to strengthen it for the lost wood - for your 2x12 example, you could drill a 4" hole (actually 3.75" is the biggest you can go since a 2x12 is actually 1.5x11.25), centered on the width, without significant concern.

If, however, you're drilling through the 2" dimension (actually 1.5", as noted above), then you can drill a 1/2" hole and fulfill the requirement. I would be extremely cautious about this, however, as it can be difficult (without a drill press) to drill exactly down the middle of a 12" board without wandering. Also, I'm not entirely sure if the 1/3 rule applies to a vertical hole. I wanted to mention it, though, since you didn't indicate which direction you were drilling.

Bear in mind that when used on edge (12" tall), the dimensional lumber gets its strength from the top fibers being in compression and the bottom fibers being in tension. I'm not sure exactly what thinning it by 1/3 would do to those forces with a vertical hole. For that, you'd probably be better off asking at the [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com) sister site.

Finally, a 3/8" hole is only bad if you'd intended it to be 1/4". It's rather more difficult to fill and drill a new hole. If you needed a 1/2" hole, instead, it's much easier to enlarge the hole (though it still has difficulty and will take time/effort to ensure the new hole is precisely centered on the old hole).

Comment: Just a feeling rather than based on calculations but I would strongly suspect that the 1/3rd rule does not apply to drilling through the depth of a beam.

Comment: I agree, @WhatEvil, that's why I suggested asking at [diy.se].

Answer (score 1):

> How does the size of a hole in dimension lumber affect strength?

The larger the hole, the greater the reduction in strength.

> Generally speaking, will a 1-1/2” hole in the dead center of a board (say, the biggest common hardware store found material: 2x12 Doug fir) weaken the structural integrity of the board regardless of the length, knots, etc.?

Generally speaking, yes. The question isn't really *whether* the board is weakened, it's *how much?* Whether it's enough to matter depends on the particulars.

> Or, put a different way: how big of a hole can one make in dimension lumber until the structure of that lumber is compromised?

Any hole you drill in a board is effectively one more defect that *could* become aa point of failure if the board is pushed to the point of failure. Every wooden board has its own set of knots, resin pockets, cracks, etc., and we compensate for those in structural applications by using boards that can be expected (even with their defects) to carry several times the largest load the board will ever see. In other words, we're careful to make sure that the board is never pushed anywhere near the point of failure.

Chances are, a 1 1/2" hole through the center of the face of a 2x12 won't make much discernible difference in strength, but whether it *actually* matters is really a decision for an engineer or at least someone with experience. For example, FreeMan explained that a board taking a load across its width (e.g. like a joist or a beam) is strong because one edge is in tension while the other is in compression; the main job of the center of the board is to maintain the separation between those two outer regions, and a smallish hole isn't likely to hurt much. But, if the load on the board is across the thickness (e.g. using the board as a ramp), then a 1.5" hole in a 12" board is like a 12.5% reduction in width, and that might create enough of a weak spot to matter.

I don't know if you're asking because someone else wants to put a hole in a beam or joist and that makes you uncomfortable, or because you want to make hole but want to make sure it's safe. In either case, consider the cost of a potential failure and get an opinion from a qualified expert if the stakes are high.